# find max number with maximum divisors

Tags: python

I have written some code, but it doesn't get the right results all the times
and I can't understand what is the problem.
For example, I changed for to be in range(2) and give it 570 and 594, the right answer is 594 16 but it gives me 570 16 but in some other cases it will work properly and I don't know what is the problem!

```
maxim=0
maxnum=0
def divisor(number):
    counter=0
    for i in range(0,number):
        if number%(i+1) == 0:
            counter+=1
    return counter


for i in range(20):
    num=int(input())
    divis=divisor(num)
    if maxim<divis:
        maxnum=num
        maxim=divis
        maxnum=num
print(maxnum,maxim)
```

Comment: Litter your code with print functions, or properly step through it with a debugger, and decipher where the logic in your code is wrong. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ is a good read for that as well.

Comment: what is `maxnum` and `maxim` suppose to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

both 594 and 570 has 16 divisors each. You are changing the `maxnum` only if the number of divisors is greater than the current `maxim`. So since 570 comes as the first input `maxnum` will be 570. change like this,

```
if maxim<=divis:
    if (maxim==divis and num>maxnum) or maxim<divis:
         maxnum=num
    maxim=divis
```

Answer (score 0):

your maxnum update condition is `maxim<divis`. `570` and `594` got same `divis`, so `maxnum` is `570`

Comment: That would appear to be the desired behaviour, to find the number with the maximum number of factors. (But if two numbers have the same max number of factors, the OP needs to pick the biggest, but that's a slightly separate matter)

Comment: the condition "maxim<divis" maybe not what he want. Sorry may the incomplete post.